# How can i remove and rename items from "Sort by" in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I am new to Prestashop and I am trying to remove from "Sort by" dropdown the default options: "Name, A to Z" and "Name, Z to A". Also i am trying to rename the option: "Relevance".
I tried to change these values from dashboard, but unfortunately i couldn't.
Does anyone know how can i fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @opnash and welcome to SO,

**Solution to Edit these entries**

You can edit these via the *International* > *Translations* tab in your PrestaShop admin panel:

[image: Translations]

You can then select *Themes translations*, your theme, your language and hit *Modify*:

[image: Translations]

Then, you can either select *Theme* > *Catalog* in the sidebar or search for "Name, Z to A" (for instance):

[image: Translations]

[image: Translations]

Lastly, just edit the text in the text box and hit *Save* and Voilà!

**Solution to Remove these entries**

Now, to delete some of these, the process would be different, you could either:

1. Override the `SortOrder()` class (in `PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Product\Search`) and filter the allowed criteria and also override the `getDefaultSortOrders()` in the `SortOrderFactory` class

*-or-*

2. Edit all the files where these Sort criteria are defined, example:

   `modules\ps_facetedsearch\src\Ps_FacetedsearchProductSearchProvider.php
   Line 127: $this->module->getTranslator()->trans('Name, Z to A', array(), 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')`

   `src\Adapter\BestSales\BestSalesProductSearchProvider.php
   Line 102: $this->translator->trans('Name, Z to A', array(), 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')`

   `src\Adapter\NewProducts\NewProductsProductSearchProvider.php
   Line 113: $this->translator->trans('Name, Z to A', array(), 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')`

   `src\Adapter\PricesDrop\PricesDropProductSearchProvider.php
   Line 107: $this->translator->trans('Name, Z to A', array(), 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')`

Please note that you can also configure the default sort criteria in your Admin Panel, via *Shop Parameters* > *Product Settings*:

[image: Default sort criteria]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! your answer was very helpful. After three days searching, i made exactly what you said and finally fixed it! I appreciate it!

Comment: @opnash, I’m glad it worked! Please don’t forget to set this answer as the accepted answer to your question to help others :)